# Passing state from parent to child functional React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I'm trying to refactor some code into separate components using Typescript / React but am having trouble sharing state between components. I'm trying to update a boolean between components and am curious about the best way to go about this.

The state can be set in either the parent or child. I'm using the `useState` hook in the parent component and then trying to set the state in the child component. In my child component, I'm getting the error `cannot find setState`.

In my parent component I'm declaring my state using:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loggedIn: false,
  });
```

I'm trying to pass state to the child component via props with:

```
      <div> <ChildComponent {...state}/> </div> // trying to pass in props, but not sure how to also pass in setting state.
```

I'm not sure how to allow state changes in the child component:

```
export const ChildComponent = (state: boolean) => { 
    setState(true)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple sandbox where you can see how to pass state from parent to child component, and how to change parent state inside child component -> https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-glitter-k9b1jc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much for all of this detail! This is great!

Answer (score 1):

First you should not pass states like this, you can use global state management for it. But by this way of passing state you can do it as props like:

```
<ChildComponent state={state.loggedIn}/>
```

and

```
export const ChildComponent = ({state}) => { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

Parent.tsx

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    loggedIn: false,
  });

  return <Child state={state} setState={setState} />;
}
```

Child.tsx

```
type Props = {
  state: { loggedIn: boolean };
  setState: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<{
      loggedIn: boolean;
    }>
  >;
};

export default function Child({ state, setState }: Props) {
  return <div>Child</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add constructor with "props" to your child component and by this you can reach the parent state:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     ...
   };   
}
```

in your code you can use this.props.propertyYouWantToUse

Answer (score 1):

Pass the setState function to the child component